# React Fetch Returning __proto__ Object When Passed as Props

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

When I pass fetched data to props it returns an extra **proto** object in my component. When I log the data in componentDidMount() before I pass it to props it returns the correct single object format I wish to use. However when I pass it down as props, it returns two objects. One with **proto** and the other is the correctly formatted object.

How do I pass the single object format down to props?

Api endpoint

```
export const fetchWorldData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(worldData);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

App.js - set fetch data to state object and pass it down to props

Note : console.log in callback

```
import React from 'react';
import { WorldDisplay } from './components';
import { fetchWorldData } from './api';


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {

    worldData: {},

  };


  async componentDidMount() {

    const fetchedWorldData = await fetchWorldData();

    this.setState(

      {

        worldData: fetchedWorldData,

      }, () => { 

      //Callback returns correctly formatted data

      console.log(fetchedWorldData);

      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {worldData} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
   // pass data as props to WorldDisplay component
        <WorldDisplay data={worldData} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Console.log of correct single object format
[image]

Component with fetched data props

```
import React from 'react';

const WorldDisplay = (data) => {
// console.log returns two objects, one __proto__ one correctly formatted
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Wold</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WorldDisplay;
```

console.log of undesired two objects

[image]

While I have tried to console.log(data.data.data) and destructuring in WorldDisplay component it returns an undefined on the first **proto** object, and I am unable to navigate the second correct object because it is referencing two objects with different response bodies. My intention here is to return only the second correct format, so I can navigate it properly.

Comment: The two `console.logs` you're seeing is the expected behavior... You can guard against null props in the child component by using `data &&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the render method of a React Component if called every time the state changes.
So what happens behind the scene is that the state property `worldData` is initially and empty object, the `WorldDisplay` component is rendered with empty object as `worldData` prop. `fetchWorldData` is an async fn, so when it returns the result, it is updates the state property `worldData`; this triggers the `render` method again.
If you want to avoid rendering the child component is the `worldData` object is null or undefined, you can render it conditionally using ternary operator

```
{worldData? <WorldDisplay data={worldData} /> : <></>}
```

And also u have to make the initial value of state variable `worldData` as `null`

Btw, you don't have to make your `componentDidMount` as async; because `fetchWorlddata` function itself is a async method.
You could re-write it as

```
  componentDidMount() {

    const worldData = fetchWorldData();

    this.setState(

      {

        worldData //Feature of ES6, this is equivalent to worldData : worldData 

      }, () => { 

      //Callback returns correctly formatted data

      console.log(fetchedWorldData);

      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I am still returning an empty object even when I render the component conditionally.  Thank you for clarifying what is going on under behind the scenes. Very helpful, it's making more sense.

Comment: also u have to make the initial value of state variable worldData as null. Because empty object ```{}``` does not equate to false.

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you so much Praveen, very simple and elegant answer, I appreciate it.